# Image onload, breaks certain scripts (Fancybox, Waypoints)?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, onload

I'm trying to preload some background images, which works fine. But when the script has finished and it goes in to my site, certain scripts / plugins fail to work... (Waypoints, Fancybox)

But all the rest such as Skrollr, jPlayer etc, work fine.

Here's my code...

```
        function preloadTrees() {

            var treesIndex = '0';

            var trees = $('.tree > span.preload');

            nextTree();

            function nextTree() {

                console.log('Tree (' + treesIndex + ') of (' + trees.length + ')');

                if (treesIndex == trees.length) {

                    alert('All Images Loaded (' + trees.length + ')');

                    preloadUI();

                }
                else {

                    var currentTree = trees[treesIndex++];

                    if (currentTree) {

                        var currentTreeObj = $(currentTree);
                        var month = currentTreeObj.data('month');

                        console.log('Loading Tree - ' + month);

                        var treeImage = new Image();

                        if (isiPad) {
                            var path = '../assets/images/sprite-trees-' + month + '@2x.png';
                        }
                        else {
                            var path = '../assets/images/sprite-trees-' + month + '.png';
                        }

                        treeImage.src = path;

                        treeImage.onload = function() {

                            $('span.' + month).each(
                                function(){
                                    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + path + ')');                                       
                                }
                            );

                            console.log('Image Loaded ' + path);

                            nextTree();

                        }

                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

The part I've narrowed it down to is:

```
treeImage.onload = function() {
```

If I remove this, the whole site works.

Why would this be?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the JS console? If so what do they say? Do you get errors on every iteration of `nextTree()` or only certain ones?

Comment: @prodigitalson No errors, what so ever...

Answer (score 0):

There are only two things i see...

First i dont see your preloader wrapped in `$(function(){ /* preloader here */})`... If you arent doing this then you are trying to use jquery to select things from the DOM before the DOM is ready.

Secondly, it may be because you are assinging the event handler directly via the onload property. Try adding an event handler instead like:

```
// vanilla JS - note youll need to make this crossbrowser
treeImage.addEventListener('onload', function(){});

// or via jquery
$(treeImage).load(function(){});
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't post all my code, but it is inside a '$(function(){ /* preloader here */})'

Adding it in to '$(treeImage).load(function(){});' still didn't work...

I have no idea why this is happening, and it's really annoying...